# Git fetch ignore global remotes

Tags: git

A tool I am using requires an entry in my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[remote "foo"]
        token = 1894701a
```

However, this means that from any git repository, git thinks that I have an extra remote called "foo".  So if I run

```
git fetch --all
```

It complains

```
fatal: 'foo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Is there a way to tell git to only fetch the remotes which are actually specified by my local git repository?  Or to not try to fetch remotes without a remote URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling the skipFetchAll option should do the trick:

```
[remote "foo"]
        token = 1894701a
        skipFetchAll = true
```

The [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-remoteltnamegtskipFetchAll) manual page has a complete list of configuration options.